# How to manipulate xml tag in xslt which contains xml tag along with its attributes as its attribute?

Tags: xml, xslt, cdata

My XML looks like this.

```
<PlayBack>
<![CDATA[<Info Event="WindowActivate" ControlName="" ControlType="" ControlRectSC="" ControlRectCL="" ParentName="" ParentType="" ControlData="" ControlMouseCL="" DialogName="" ExeName=""  MouseButton="" />]]>
</PlayBack>
```

I want to fetch the Info tag attributes values and store them in some variables.

result expected

```
<xsl:variable name="Event">
      "WindowActivate"    //here i need this value
</xsl:variable>
```

Comment: Your XML looks like this `]]>` ? & also post what you've tried.

Comment: Be clear with your codes...

Comment: Hello sir, i am new to xslt and xml. the xml file has above format and containd hundreds of <Playback> tags and it again contains CDATA in which a tag is defined with some attributes .i want to store these attribute values in some variables is that possible in xslt?

Comment: A variable is a something you use in the course of a transformation process and not beyond. It is not and cannot be the result of the transformation. What is the actual output you want to get in the end?

Answer (score 0):

In the example you've given, there *is* no Info tag - just a string of text which just happens to look to human eyes as if it contained an info tag. That's what CData is - a way of storing text without interpreting it as tags.

If you want to use it, you need to do 2 passes. The first extracts the data and writes it out to an intermediate file using xsl:value-of (*not* copy-of - you need to get rid of the CDATA tag). The second reads in the result and can then use the tags.

Comment: In xml there are hundreds of <Playback> tag which itself contains this CDATA tag  .so if i follow 2 step procedurre then i need to create hundreds of intermediate file or in a single file i need to write 100 times.its a hectic procedure ..is there any other solution you have?

Comment: No, just a single file. The input copies all tags, attributes and text nodes by default but uses value-of for the playback children. The resulting single file is a copy of the source but without CDATA tags under the Playback node. When that's read into the next pass, the child nodes should be readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can download an XSLT 3.0 processor like Saxon 9.6 HE from http://saxon.sourceforge.net/ and then use the `parse-xml` function introduced in XPath 3.0:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="PlayBack">
  <xsl:variable name="info" select="parse-xml(.)/Info"/>
  <xsl:variable name="event" select="$info/@Event"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="$event"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you need to use an XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 processor then you need to check whether it supports or allows you to implement a similar extension function, if not, you need to use the already suggested two step solution of transforming in a first step to a new XML document (`<xsl:template match="PlayBack"><xsl:copy><xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/></xsl:copy></xsl:template>`) and then process that file with a second stylesheet.

Comment: Thanx for the solution.....                                                                           The application is being built is in C# and I  want to know whether application at client side also needs the installation of saxon or not needed? because by default visual studio supports xslt 1.0 and i am using XslCompiledTransform().Transform() method to convert xml file in my application

Comment: If you want to use XSLT 3.0 with .NET then you need to install the .NET version of Saxon 9.6 or you could try XmlPrime as well as I think they only support XSLT 2.0 so far but already support use of functions like `parse-xml`. Without any installation of such a processor you can't use XSLT 3.0 or the function `parse-xml`.